# Aggregation. I want to count record in mongo and I then want to multiply that count by a field in a different collection

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation

This is *Invoice Collection*:

```
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "1", "Total" : "22.50", "FoodId" : "1", "SupplierType" : "Meat"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "2", "Total" : "22.50", "FoodId" : "2", "SupplierType" : "Meat"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "3", "Total" : "12.50", "FoodId" : "3", "SupplierType" : "Veg"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "3", "Total" : "12.50", "FoodId" : "3", "SupplierType" : "Veg"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "4", "Total" : "12.50", "FoodId" : "4", "SupplierType" : "Veg"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "5", "Total" : "15.00", "FoodId" : "5", "SupplierType" : "Meat"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "6", "Total" : "19.00", "FoodId" : "6", "SupplierType" : "Meat"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "7", "Total" : "10.00", "FoodId" : "7", "SupplierType" : "Veg"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "8", "Total" : "10.00", "FoodId" : "8", "SupplierType" : "Veg"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "9", "Total" : "10.00", "FoodId" : "9", "SupplierType" : "Veg"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })   
db.Invoice.insert({"InvoiceNo" : "10", "Total" : "25.00", "FoodId" : "10", "SupplierType" : "Meat"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

And this is *Food Collection*:

```
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "1", "FoodType" : "Steak","BestBeforeDate" : "07/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "2", "FoodType" : "Steak","BestBeforeDate" : "07/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "3", "FoodType" : "Carrot","BestBeforeDate" : "09/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "3", "FoodType" : "Carrot","BestBeforeDate" : "17/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "4", "FoodType" : "Peas","BestBeforeDate" : "09/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "5", "FoodType" : "Ribbs","BestBeforeDate" : "05/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "6", "FoodType" : "Ribbs","BestBeforeDate" : "05/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "7", "FoodType" : "Chips","BestBeforeDate" : "30/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "8", "FoodType" : "Chips","BestBeforeDate" : "30/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "9", "FoodType" : "Chips","BestBeforeDate" : "30/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })    
db.Food.insert({"FoodId" : "10", "FoodType" : "Chicken","BestBeforeDate" : "30/05/2018",})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

I want to multiply the total by the count function for the *Food Collection*.
Next I want to count how many records where `FoodType` is equal to "Steak". I want to multiply the result from the count by the total in the *Invoice Collection*.

This is the command that I thought would work:

```
db.Food.aggregate(
  [
    { $project: 
      { date: 1, item: 1, 
        total: { $multiply: 
          [
            {"FoodType": "Carrot"}.count(), "Total"}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

I want to count the number of steak entries in the *Food Table*. Then I want to multiply that result by the total corresponding price in the *Invoice Table*.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What tables are in use and what do they look like?

Comment: Hey Jamie, welcome to StackOverflow. There's really no need for so many examples of how you insert data into the db...  Your question is also not so clear, maybe you can make it a bit clearer by adding a written (or code) example.

Comment: I incorporated your relevant comments into the question.